# Help me clarify this question about depth of villains' backstories

Tags: discussion

My intended question is

> Is it possible to write childrens' entertainment while still giving villains' backstories the depth of that is typical of adult entertainment?

And while I am thinking to define depth with Single Issue Psychology and Freudian Excuse being the 'shallowest' backstories possible... To me, that feels unfair and inaccurate...

So, can you guys give me a better way to gage the 'depth' of a backstory?